# Passing an int as the object for performSelectorOnMainThread:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, primitive

I need to invoke:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(chooseURL:) withObject:myIndex waitUntilDone:YES];
```

But my problem is that `myIndex` is an `int`, and **NOT** an object. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap the int in an object since int is a primitive type and not an object. For example:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(chooseURL:) 
                       withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myIndex] 
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Of course you will have to edit your chooseURL: method to accept a NSNumber instead of an int.
To unwrap:

```
int myInt = [myIndex intValue];
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to go the opposite direction, reconverting the NSNumber to int again?

Comment: @Winston: Steve already told you how; the last line of his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create an NSNumber from the int

[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt];

Comment: Great! Is there a way to go the opposite direction, reconverting the NSNumber to int again?

Comment: Sure is: int i = [myNumber integerValue];

Answer (score 2):

Use the GCD version of `performSelectorOnMainThread:...`:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self chooseURL:myIndex];
});
```

The main queue is always on the main thread.

Just don't use `dispatch_sync()` while you're already on the main thread, or you'll deadlock. Check if necessary:

```
dispatch_queue_t mainQ = dispatch_get_main_queue();
if( mainQ != dispatch_get_current_queue() ){
    dispatch_sync(mainQ, ^{
        [self chooseURL:myIndex];
    });
}
else {
    [self chooseURL:myIndex];
}
```

For `waitUntilDone:NO`, you can use `dispatch_async()`, which *is* okay to use from the same thread.

Comment: Your answer is great and I learned a lot from it! And it also works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber can be classed as an object so use [NSNumber numberwithint:myindex]